# How do i write O(n) Program for number of subsets that start and end with certain digit

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

We take an array in which every index is filled with some digit. We want to find out from this array, the subsets which start with 3 and end with 7.

For instance:

`1,2,5,3,6,7,3,3,7,0,3,4,9,7,8`

The answer for this will be 8 but we don't have to print out these subsets:

```
3,6,7
3,6,7,3,3,7
3,6,7,3,3,7,0,3,4,9,7
3,3,7
3,3,7,0,3,4,9,7
3,7
3,7,0,3,4,9,7
3,4,9,7
```

The code:

```
  int o_n_alg(int arr[], int size)
  {
    // To fill with O(n) Algorithm
  }

  int main(){
     int size = 1000000;
     int *array = new int[size];
     int ans_n;

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
       cin >> array[i];


     ans_n = o_n_alg(array, size);
  }
```

Can anyone help how can I fill up `int o_n_alg(int arr[], int size)` function?

Comment: sweep left to right and keep track of the number of seen 3s. For each 7 that you see you add the number of the current already seen 3s to the result.

Comment: I am so appriceate user1984 thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You might use the following:

```
int o_n_alg(int arr[], int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    int count3 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == 3) {
            ++count3;
        } else if (arr[i] == 7) {
            result += count3;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

as `7` ends any previous `3`.